# how to deal with navigation-bar?

Tags: android, reflection, navigationbar

Some devices like Huawei Mate7 has navigation-bar like following shows.
My question:
1, how to get height of navi-bar?
2, how to get notification when navi-bar shows and hide ?

I tried reflection to find some useful information, failed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Getting the height is easy:

```
    Resources resources = getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0)
    {
        height = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
```

That will return the height of the nav bar in pixels.

As for notification that it's been hidden, I don't believe there is an event for that.  You have to explicitly tell your app to hide the nav bar.  It doesn't hide on it's own.

Additional code to detect if there is a hardware menu button:

```
if (!ViewConfiguration.get(MainActivity.this).hasPermanentMenuKey() )
{
    Resources resources = getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0)
    {
        height = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
}
```

This well tell you if there is a hardware menu button on most phones.  Some models will still report that there is no menu key.  In those cases, you'll have to devise something to know the models that do that and account for it.

Comment: I try the code, for example, it returns 144 in a device without navigation-bar. So I am not sure whether you are right. Maybe navigation-bar is something else ?

Comment: No,  that is the navigation bar. I use that code in my own apps. Of course not every phone has a navigation bar, because some phones have hardware menu buttons. And some phones will have both.

Comment: I will try this on some different devices.

Comment: Did your question get answered?